# How to get Java Object from Json returned by Google Custom Api search

Tags: java, json, google-custom-search

I have following code for retrieving web search results through google custom api

```
package google.custom.api.results.google.custom.api;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class handler {


    public static boolean searchAndSaveGoogleCustomSearch() throws  UnsupportedEncodingException 
    {
        String apiKey="AIzaSyB21aUCd8HYMsHgo7APH-98ah-8tLgkPFM";
        String cxId="005621018181405156379:yvdukowvdte";

        String keyToSearch="News";


        String urlToSearch="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" +apiKey+ "&cx="+cxId
                +"&alt=json"+"&q="+keyToSearch;


        try {
            URL url=new URL(urlToSearch);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
              conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader ( ( conn.getInputStream() ) ) );
              GoogleCustomApiResult result = new Gson().fromJson(br, GoogleCustomApiResult.class);
              System.out.println(result);
              conn.disconnect();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

            searchAndSaveGoogleCustomSearch();
            System.out.println("Google Crawl done.");
    }
}
```

And here's how i have been trying to retrieve the java object from json results

```
package google.custom.api.results.google.custom.api;

import java.util.List;

public class GoogleCustomApiResult 
{

      private String link;
      private String htmlFormattedUrl;

      private List<GoogleCustomApiResult> items;

      public String getLink() {
        return link;
      }

      public String getUrl() {
        return htmlFormattedUrl;
      }

      public void setUrl(String htmlFormattedUrl) {
        this.htmlFormattedUrl = htmlFormattedUrl;
      }

      public List<GoogleCustomApiResult> getItems() {
        return items;
      }

      public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
      }

      public void setGroups(List<GoogleCustomApiResult> items) {
        this.items = items;
      }

      public void getThing (int i) {
        System.out.println(items.get(i));
      }

      public String getLink(int i) {
        return items.get(i).toString();
      }

      public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s", link);
      }  
}
```

And also using this class

```
package com.til.et.mynewsletter.core.parser.json.google;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomApiResult 
{
    private String kind;
    private String title;
    private String htmlTitle;
    private String link;
    private String displayLink;
    private String snippet;
    private String htmlSnippet;
    private String cacheId;
    private String formattedUrl;
    private String htmlFormattedUrl;
    //private String htmlSnippet;


    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }
    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getHtmlTitle() {
        return htmlTitle;
    }
    public void setHtmlTitle(String htmlTitle) {
        this.htmlTitle = htmlTitle;
    }
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
    public String getDisplayLink() {
        return displayLink;
    }
    public void setDisplayLink(String displayLink) {
        this.displayLink = displayLink;
    }
    public String getSnippet() {
        return snippet;
    }
    public void setSnippet(String snippet) {
        this.snippet = snippet;
    }
    public String getHtmlSnippet() {
        return htmlSnippet;
    }
    public void setHtmlSnippet(String htmlSnippet) {
        this.htmlSnippet = htmlSnippet;
    }
    public String getCacheId() {
        return cacheId;
    }
    public void setCacheId(String cacheId) {
        this.cacheId = cacheId;
    }
    public String getFormattedUrl() {
        return formattedUrl;
    }
    public void setFormattedUrl(String formattedUrl) {
        this.formattedUrl = formattedUrl;
    }
    public String getHtmlFormattedUrl() {
        return htmlFormattedUrl;
    }
    public void setHtmlFormattedUrl(String htmlFormattedUrl) {
        this.htmlFormattedUrl = htmlFormattedUrl;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GoogleCustomApiResult [title=" + title + ", link=" + link + ", snippet=" + snippet + ", cacheId="
                + cacheId + ", formattedUrl=" + formattedUrl + ", htmlFormattedUrl=" + htmlFormattedUrl + "]";
    }
```

But the java object returned is null every time. I am new to Json and do not know how to parse the result to get the java object populated with values. 
The Url is returning the result but the values are not going into java object. please help me out.

Comment: I tried your complete URL and get an error code json: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyB21aUCd8HYMsHgo7APH-98atLgkPFM&cx=005621018181405156379:yvduvdte&alt=json&q=News

Comment: What does the line System.out.println(result); in the method 'searchAndSaveGoogleCustomSearch()' print out ?

Comment: Is the type of `items` in the `GoogleCustomApiResult` class equals to `List<GoogleCustomApiResult>` not `List<CustomApiResult 
>` ??

Comment: System.out.println(result) prints the following: GoogleCustomApiResult [title=null, link=null, snippet=null, cacheId=null, formattedUrl=null, htmlFormattedUrl=null]

Comment: try the url now, it will work fine

Comment: Your key and cx are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your response you're not mapping exactly the same json structure with you model `GoogleCustomApiResult` cause a lot of fields are missing.

You have two options:

1. Map the exactly json structure (Don't try to do this cause you have a giant json!)
2. Parse your response to get the list of objects you want (recommended).

Take a look at `JsonParser` in Gson API.

Also correct the error in your model class pointed by @Maraboc.